# How to find my way to a quest location?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to get to Dead Crone Rock for the quest Pieces of the Past. There is a pommel of Mehrunes' Razor that I need to retrieve for Silus Vesuius. Right now, I'm standing at the city gates in Markath.

Comment: Didn't know that such spell existed! Nice answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Clairvoyance spell, which can be found in Embershard Mine (the first mine you will see on your way from Helgen to Riverwood) or bought from the Riverwood Trader, various jarls' wizards or Drevis Neloren at the College of Winterhold.

Clairvoyance will lead you to the nearest quest or player marker, so make sure you don't have unnecessary quests tracked if you're trying to get to a particular location or quest target.